# Forward Index Implementation in google

Tags: indexing, search-engine, information-retrieval

I am trying to develop a search engine in my free time modeled after google.

I am using the original google research paper listed here: http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html

However I am having a few problems here. To be exact I am having problem developing the forward index.

In the paper it says:

> If a document contains words that fall into a particular barrel, the docID is recorded into the barrel, followed by a list of wordID's with hitlists which correspond to those words.

Now there are two problem with in this statement. First who decides which words out of the huge lexicon goes into the Forward Barrels? Do all of them go. Second is the meaning of the word corresponding. Does it mean words that actually appear in that document after the previous word or something else?

I am really new to Search Engines and would really appreciate any Information Retrival Expert helping me on this. If moderators think that this question belong in some other Stack Exchange site please do so.

Answer (score 0):

First Question:
The string value of every word is mapped into an integer (by a hash function). This is because integers are far more easier to handle than strings. You can then define ranges (buckets or bins or whatever else you might want to call them) over these integer values, e.g.

- term ids 0 to 1000 => Bin-1
- term ids 1001 to 2000 => Bin-2 
  and so on.

Second question:
The context information is typically not used. A word is simply a term present in a document, such as the terms "the", "quick", "brown" etc.

Since you said you are new to IR, a good way to start would be to read an introductory book to IR, e.g. the book by Manning and Schutze.